# ArcObjects 10.1

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

just updated to 10.1 and I'm having issues moving from 10.1. 
I get the errors with my ADF reference when trying to create custom tool bars

examples:

```
'BaseToolbar' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses'.
```

Any suggestions on how to convert? I have the following references imported:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local
```

Comment: What Visual Studio version/type are you using? What .NET Framework are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF and it has rectified my problem